# error: The argument type 'UserModel? Function(User?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserModel Function(User?)'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error in flutter.

UserModel is a class

```
class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  UserModel({this.uid});
}
```

And the code where this error is coming up is

```
  Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

Complete code:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }


  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user!;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword( String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user!;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signUpWithEmailAndPassword( String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user!;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;

    }
  }



}
```

Comment: Can you share what `_userFromFirebaseUser` is?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `_userFromFirebaseUser` is defined something like this,

```
UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
```

So this means that you are saying, your `_userFromFirebaseUser` might return a `UserModel` or might return a `null`.

One way to fix this is to make your `getter` return `Stream<UserModel?>` instead of `Stream<UserModel>`.

```
Stream<UserModel?> get user {
  return _auth.authStateChanges()
    .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

Now your `getter` might return a `UserModel` or it might return a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'm glad I found the solution :

```
UserModel _userFromFirebase (User? user){
    
   return UserModel(uid: user!.uid);
  }
Stream<UserModel> get user{
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
```

and if _userFromFirebase appears error use:

```
 _userFromFirebase(user.user) ;
```